# Spilt a string into half and join it with another string

Tags: c, string, split

I wanna ask if say i have a string "abcdefgh" and I want to half it to become "abcd" and "efgh" and store it into their own strings say I call it "UpperHalf" and "LowerHalf". So the way to do this is to first make use of the strlen() to find out the length of my input and half it? Then I would need to use strcpy() and copy it to their respective strings right?

Actually I don't even know if my code makes any sense. Anyone can give me some comments on it?

I realized I only need to consider even input numbers which means I do not need to worry about odd inputs. Previously I was trying to spilt a 1d string into half and then strcat it with something else. But now I am given a series of input strings that are stored in 2d array format. In this case, how do I retrieve these strings and manipulate them as though it is the same as the previous 1d case? I don't think I need to use for loops? Can I just point to the row?

```
int d = strlen(str); // just an example where str = the characters inside my string
strcpy(temp, &str[0]); // store original string into a temp string starting from 0 to \0
str[d/2] = '\0';
strcpy(UpperHalf, &str[0]); // starts copying from position 0 to \0 which is the half way point
str[0] = temp;  //revert back to normal -> Does this line even make sense?
strcpy(LowerHalf, &str[d/2]);
```

Comment: replace '/0' with '\0'

Comment: thanks. I corrected it, but logic-wise any comments? Kinda first time doing strings.

Comment: You *are* aware of that arrays decays naturally to pointer to their first element? Meaning if you have an array `str` and pass it to a function taking a pointer, what the compiler will pass is effectively the same as `&str[0]`. So you don't have to be explicit about it, just pass `str` and it will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you definitely need to consider the odd number string lengths.  There are code approaches which will either round it up or down (so that the first or second string will have the extra character) but you need to decide which way you want it to go.

Looking at your code, I would suggest that using the temp string is not needed.  You can copy directly from the original 'str' and save that memory and processor overhead.  A few changes will be needed:
Currently you're overwriting one of the characters in your source string with the '\0' character, and your second strcpy is starting at that '\0' which will return a zero length string.
To copy a fixed number of characters, you can use strncpy which will work better here than strcpy by simplifying your code and keeping things clear.
Don't forget to terminate your strings with a \0, or you could initialise the buffers with 0 values as I have here.

So, an example might look like this:

```
char UpperHalf[MAX_LENGTH];
char LowerHalf[MAX_LENGTH];

int l = strlen(str);
int half = l / 2;
memset(LowerHalf, '\0', MAX_LENGTH);
strncpy(LowerHalf, str, half);
memset(UpperHalf, '\0', MAX_LENGTH);
strncpy(UpperHalf, str + half, l - half);
```

This will put the longer part of an odd length string into the UpperHalf char array.
To make the code safe you should also consider doing length comparisons to ensure that all strings will fit in the buffers provided (with at least one character left over for the string terminating \0 character).

Comment: The expression `L / 2` is an integer division and will yield an integer. I don't think you need floating-point arithmetic here. Just take `L/2` for the left substring and `L - L/2` for the right one. (I've used an upper-case ell here, because otherwise it looks too much like the fraction one half.)

Comment: Yes that will work too.  To keep it neat that way I would want to store the first division into a temporary variable: int lowHalf = L /  2; and then the subtraction for the other half would be clear as L - lowHalf.  Doing it with two separate divides risks errors if only one of them is rounded up.  Note that this approach puts the short string in LowerHalf if done exactly as described.

Comment: What do you mean with "too"? Your approach doesn't work. (Or, more gently put, it works only in theory.) Say `L` is 7. Then `L/2` is 3, not 3.5, because this is an integer division. 3 + 0.5 is 3.5, which will be truncated to just 3 again on conversion to int. You could say `L/2.0 + 0.5` to move the middle element to the left subarray. But that can be expressed as `(L + 1) / 2`, for which you don't need any floating-point maths.

Comment: Ack yes of course you're correct.  I've spent too long with type promoted languages!

Comment: Btw, for the memset portion of the code, you're initializing the entire array with '\0' right? But if you do strncpy for the lowerhalf, strncpy(LowerHalf, str, half); will copy the characters in str, from 0-4? In the case of a length 8 character. But for the upperhalf, isn't l-half going to give me 4 as well and won't I be copying from 0-4 as well?

Comment: @Morde Thanks, yes you're correct about the copy start for upper half and I've fixed that using a pointer arithmetic approach (your &str[half] approach will also work but is a little 'wordy' for C).  I'm not clear on what you're saying about the memset - perhaps I should clarify that '\0' is the string terminator character which evaluates to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must first use `strlen` to get the length of the input string, and halve it to give the length of `upper_half`:

```
size_t length = strlen(str);
size_t upper_length = length / 2;
size_t lower_length = length - upper_length;
```

In this case, if the length of the input string is odd, then due to integer division, `upper_length` will equal `lower_length - 1`, e.g.:

```
length == 3
upper_length == 3 / 2 == 1
lower_length == 3 - 1 == 2
```

It’s easier to do the actual copying without modifying the original string, as your code is doing.

You must allocate space to store the copies of the string halves, with null terminators:

```
char *upper_half = malloc(upper_length + 1);
char *lower_half = malloc(lower_length + 1);
```

Then use `memcpy` to copy the string data:

```
memcpy(upper_half, &str[0], upper_length);
upper_half[upper_length] = '\0';
```

(Similarly for `lower_half`.)

`strcpy` copies characters until a null byte, while `memcpy` copies a given number of bytes.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little more on memcpy and memset? Because I have only learn the normal strcpy, strlen, strcmp and strcat.

Comment: @Morde: `memcpy(destination, source, count)` copies `count` bytes from `source` to `destination`. If you wanted to do this with *only* `strcpy`, you would need to do basically as you thought: replace the character at the end of the first string with a null terminator, then restore it when you’re done. `char temp = str[upper_length]; str[upper_length] = '\0'; strcpy(upper_half, &str[0]); str[upper_length] = temp; strcpy(lower_half, &str[upper_length]);` However, this code is a little harder to reason about than the version that simply copies the data out directly.

Comment: "... while `memcpy` copies a given number of bytes ..." but there is also a `strncpy` :) (Oh well, I see it's missing from OPs shortlist anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

While it is fine to use all the standard functions to copy the lower/upper halves to separate strings, you can also split the string using only pointers and a separate buffer to hold the lower-half of the string.

Basically, you can find the length of the string, adjust the odd/even location of the midpoint (if desired to always but the additional char on odd lengths in the lower-half), and then use a simple loop to copy to lower-half. At the end of the loop, the pointer used points to the upper-half (or you can simply use the pointer for the location of the midpoint). A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s string\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char lower_half[MAXC] = {0};    /* array to hold lower_half */
    char *p = argv[1];              /* poiter to string         */
    char *pl = lower_half;          /* pointer to lower_half    */
    char *split = NULL;             /* pointer to split point   */
    size_t len = 0;                 /* string length            */

    for (; *p; p++);        /* find end of string   */
    len = p - argv[1];      /* get string length    */
    p = argv[1];            /* reset pointer        */
    split = p + len/2;      /* set split at middle  */
    if (len & 1) split++;   /* if odd, add 1        */

    for (; p < split; p++)  /* for each ch < split  */
        *pl++ = *p;         /* copy to lower_half   */
    *pl = 0;                /* null-terminate       */

    /* print results */
    printf ("\n lower_half : '%s'    upper_half : '%s'\n",
            lower_half, split);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_half 123456789

 lower_half : '12345'    upper_half : '6789'

$ ./bin/str_half 1234567890

 lower_half : '12345'    upper_half : '67890'
```

Regardless of whether you use pointers or use `strlen`, `strncpy`, or `memcpy`, etc., just be sure you `null-terminate` the separated strings. Above, the explicit null-termination is not required due to `lower_half` being initialized to all `0` at the beginning. However, it is good practice to always insure your code is null-terminating your strings.